# How to add an "alt" attribute equivalent to a unicode character (in a span)?

Tags: html, css, unicode, alt

I am currently working on a yelp-ish SPA that allows users to rate locations on several criteria, one of which is romantic potential. If the location is romantic, a lips/kiss icon is displayed.

I currently have the unicode character for lips  within a `span`. When my user hovers over the character, I would like to have the text "Romantic" displayed.

I was hoping I could just add an `alt` attribute to an html element housing the unicode character, but apparently `alt` only works on `img`, `input`, and `area`, none of which seem appropriate.

Is there a simple, html solution?

Comment: you're confusing alt with title.  alt does not display anything on hover; title does.

Comment: Quite right, I wasn't even aware of title. Thanks!

Comment: (The [`area` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#the-area-element) is not deprecated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Try the demo below.

```html
<span title="Romantic"></span>
```

More info about the `title` attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp).